# how to make the layout alignment not change if the language changed from English to Arabic Android Developing

Tags: android, layout, alignment, right-to-left, left-to-right

I am developing an Android app and when i try the app on android phone with Arabic language alignment of the text-view and edit-text change i wan't change them.

**Example: (TextView)(EditText)** this when the phone language English
when language changed to Arabic layout changed to **(EditText)(TextView)**
 i want them **(TextView)(EditText)** even if the phone language Arabic or English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare in your app manifest that your app supports RTL mirroring.

Specifically, add

```
android:supportsRtl="true" to the <application> element
```

in your manifest file.

for more [refer here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set application locale on launch of your application. after your app layout will not change for any device specific locale.

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("us"); //US English Locale
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```